# Sort an elasicsearch resultset based on a filter term

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

For an ecommerce I am implementing elasticsearch in order to get a sorted and paginated resultset of product ids for a category.

I have a product document which looks like this:

```
PUT /products_test/product/1
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "foobar",
  "sort": 102,
  "categories": [
                  "28554568",
                  "28554577",
                  "28554578"
  ],
}
```

To get the resultset I filter and sort like this:

```
POST /products/_search
{
    "filter": {
        "term": {
         "categories": "28554666"
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
        { "sort" : {"order" : "asc"}}
    ]
}
```

However, how I now learned the requirement is, that the product sorting depends on the category. Looking at the example above this means that I need to add a different sort value for each value in the categories array and depending on the category that I filter by I want to sort by the corresponding sort value.

The document should look something like this:

```
PUT /products_test/product/1
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "foobar",
  "categories": [
    { "id": "28554568", "sort": "102" },
    { "id": "28554577", "sort": "482" },
    { "id": "28554578", "sort": "2" }
  ]
}
```

My query now should be able to sort something like this:

```
POST /products/_search
{
    "filter": {
        "term": {
         "categories.id": "28554666"
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
        { "categories.{filtered_category_id}.sort" : {"order" : "asc"}}
    ]
}
```

Is it somehow possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to store your categories as nested documents. If not, Elasticsearch will not know what sort is associated with what category ID.

Then, you will have to sort on the nested documents, by also filtering to choose the right one.

Here's a runnable example you can play with: https://www.found.no/play/gist/47282a07414e1432de6d

```
curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "categories": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'


curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"id":1,"title":"foobar","categories":[{"id":"28554568","sort":102},{"id":"28554577","sort":482},{"id":"28554578","sort":2}]}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"id":2,"title":"barbaz","categories":[{"id":"28554577","sort":0}]}
'

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "categories",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "categories.id": {
                        "value": 28554577
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "categories.sort": {
            "order": "asc",
            "nested_filter": {
                "term": {
                    "categories.id": 28554577
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the answer I was looking for.